# Is it possible to use Hour parameter in Google Analytics API request? Python

Tags: python, api, filter, google-analytics

hopefully this is a simple one. I wanted to pull data from GA every hour. I know that there is an end and start date parameters available. Is it possible to have an Hour filter on the request so I can run a query every 60 minutes and have the data being appended to a file, I don't want to pull all available data for a day every time I send a request.

Thanks!

sampak

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

See Filters
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics#filtering_2

Don't forget to consider usage quota to adjust how frequent you get data
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas

And remind that "intraday" data isn't "stable" and is re-processed before becoming consistent on the next day (or day after, depending on the volume you collect and if you are a 360 customer or not)

(these apply to [Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs), is it the version you are referring to?)